# Handle different application using C++

Tags: c++, windows

Is there any way to control other windows application using c++/qt?

I have: 1000 files of specific image format and an application that can open them. This application can use "Save as..." function to save these files in ".JPEG" format one by one. I want to do this automatically.

Is there any technique to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: IMHO C++ is not the correct tool for this job.  Something like AutoIt comes to mind for something like this.

Comment: Unless there's an explicit C++ API for that program, using C++ doesn't sound very reasonable.

Comment: @NathanOliver will look into it, thanks

Comment: IIRC, the first part is fairly trivial. Choosing a meny entry is just [`SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MENUSELECT)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646352(v=vs.85).aspx). However, you then probably need to pass the filename, and that might be quite a bit harder.

Comment: It's not a "programming" answer, but if you just need jpeg conversion, instead of your one by one application, you can consider image batch converter like [xnconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/)

Comment: Check out UI Automation.

Answer (score 0):

Using QT you have the possibility to run a separate process using a [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) instance.

Specifically suppose that your external application accepts input parameters (e.g. the filepath to load and the filepath where to store the result.

```
QProcess shell;

QStringList argv;
//[setup argument-list]

shell.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
shell.start(commandPath, argv); 
shell.waitForFinished();
```

Notice that QProcess can be uses as an IO stream. This is useful to interact with the process (e.g. to retrieve progress information):

```
shell.start(commandPath, argv); 
shell.waitForReadyRead();

while(shell.state() == QProcess::Running || !shell.atEnd()){
   auto s = shell.readLine()

   //[do something with the current line of the process output]
}

QProcess::ExitStatus es =  shell.exitStatus () ;
```

Of course the external process must accept input parameters and provide feedback through its standard output to solve your problem.